# Exception when multiplying price and area

Tags: vb.net

I have almost finished making the program but I am stuck with making the bill.

My program allows the user to select from a paintype by making a choice from 1-3. 1 is for luxury which is `£1.75` another for standard which is `£1.00`, and the third choice "economy" which is 0.40p. For the bill I have to multiply the price of the paint by the area of the room.
I have tried doing this:

```
    Dim paintprice As Double

    paintprice = paintType * areaofroom

    Console.WriteLine(paintType * areaofroom)

    Console.WriteLine(" You are a winner")

    Console.ReadLine()
```

After doing this I get the error message: `conversion from sting luxury to type double is`

Comment: Where's the string "luxury" in your code?

Comment: you haven't included your whole error message

Comment: Turn option strict ON: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: We need to see how you declare paintType and areaofroom. Are they doubles as well? It looks like they are strings...

Comment: @macoms01 It's not `painTtype`, it's `PAINtype`! Quote:`"..select from a paintype by making.."` ;)

Comment: The paintype variable is dimmed as an string.

Comment: This is the full error messageConversion from string "Luxury " to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: You'll need to parse the text into double: `Double.Parse(luxury)`

Comment: This is the coding I used to allow the user to select from one of the paints                                              <code>Console.WriteLine("Select a type of paint.")
        Console.WriteLine("1 -Luxery = £1.75")
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Standard = £1.00")
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Economy = 0.40")
        Console.Write("Make a selection (1-3): ")

Comment: @user3210334 Please add all relevant code in your question and not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `paintype` might contains a "£", you could try this, as Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå suggested:

```
Dim paintprice As Double

Dim priceweight As Double = If(paintype.Contains("£"), _
Double.Parse(paintype.Remove(paintype.IndexOf("£"), 1)), Double.Parse(paintype)) 
' This will remove the "£" and convert `paintype` to a double

paintprice = priceweight * areaofroom
```

Comment: No hard feelings bro! ;)

Comment: I don't know how to create a chat room:p

Comment: Oh, ok. If you wanted to chat about soccer, though, I think I know how to create one. ;) But it wouldn't be private

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

Come to think of it, you're trying to convert a string value `"luxury"` to double.

```
Dim d As Double = CType("luxury", Double)
```

which will throw:

`Conversion from string "luxury" to type 'Double' is not valid.`

**Solution**

You'll need to do:

```
Dim paintTypeDouble As Double = 0.0#

Select Case paintType
    Case "luxury"
        paintTypeDouble = 1.75#
    Case "standard"
        paintTypeDouble = 1.0#
    Case "economy"
        paintTypeDouble = 0.4#
    End Select
```

Then, assuming `areaofroom` is a integral type:

```
paintprice = (paintTypeDouble * areaofroom)
```

Comment: The answer always comes up as 0 once the program is run

Comment: Meaning it does not multiply the painttype price by the area of the room